# Getting url is invalid trying to create webtile

Tags: microsoft-band

I tried http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KCIC.xml. The browsers display this URL fine but the webtile tool at https://developer.microsoftband.com/WebTile/AssignData said the url is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It'n not a valid RSS or Atom valid format. You will need make an app, try Yahoo Weather:

https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/